# Gnome terminator ignores global dark theme

Tags: debian, gnome, terminator

I turned on global dark theme in gnome-tweak-tool and launched terminator. It still has a white bar at its top. How can i fix this?

[image: Look here]

Comment: I gess it is due to the fact that Terminator uses GTK2, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old question, but Terminator now uses gtk3, as per the [release notes](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/releases/tag/v2.0):

> Terminator 2.0 - Migration to Gtk 3 and Python 3 complete

But there is no dark mode support still as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Terminator still uses gtk2.  There is a gtk3 development branch.  Instructions/caveats for Ubuntu-ish distros: http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/2015/09/so-you-want-to-try-terminator-gtk3.html

An Arch user has added it to the AUR as well: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/terminator-gtk3-bzr/